# Graphing functions while varying one parameter

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a Matlab function, and I want to graph it while varying a certain parameter from 100 to 1000
it goes like this: [c, errorrange, i] = function [g1, g2, x];
I want to graph x and c while varying x

The function itself
...............

```
  function [root,e, i]=func(xl,xu,e_stopping, z)
    if ((((xl^4)/(20*z)-(3*z^2*xl^2)/50)*((xu^4)/(20*z)-(3*z^2*xu^2)/50)) > 0) 
        error('the intials wont work');
    end
    root = z/2+z*2;
    e = 2;
    i = 2;
    end
```

...............

I thought of something like this:

...

```
for i = 100: 1000
[c, error] = fund(1000, 2000,0, i);
A(i) = c;
end
for i = 1: 99
A(i) = 0;
end
plot(A);
```

...
but it won't work; sorry, if my question is not good, I am new to Matlab.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear because the variables you say you want to plot are not identified in your code. Although it doesn't matter what you call them in your function (like you say in your comments), if you are not clear in your question, then we have to guess that i=x, or A=x, or whatever you intended.

I'm still not sure exactly what you want to plot, but this should be close enough to get you started. Basically, it looks like you don't need any `for` loops, you just need to pass a vector input into your function.

```
A = 1:1:100; % create this vector however you need
[c, error] = func(1000, 2000, 0, A);

plot(A, c)
xlabel('my input A', 'FontSize', 10)
ylabel('my function output c', 'FontSize', 10)
title("my graph", 'FontSize', 12)



function [root, e, i] = func(xl, xu, e_stopping, z)
    root = z/2 + z*2;
    e = 2;
    i = 2;
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for replying.

Comment: It tells me "matrix dimensions don't agree." Also, my function gives three answers, and you're using one variable only - how is this possible?

Comment: you didn't provide a function, so I made one up as an example. in your post, your function gives 2 answers and requires 3 inputs (answers/outputs are on the left, in brackets; inputs are on the right, in parentheses)

Comment: if you revise your question add a "dumbed-down" version (i.e., easily reproducible) of your function and inputs, it will be easier to help

Comment: x = 100:5:1000
[root, e, itr] = func(0,5,0, x);
Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
That is the error

Comment: I don't want to put my function because, when I submit it, I will be accused of plagiarism and I can get in serious trouble for this. So,I thought it would be ok if I just mention the problem.
Thank you for your help

Comment: then compose a simple "dummy function" that is only a couple lines long to capture the fact that you have 3 inputs and 2 outputs. update your question with a complete, reproducible code attempt

Comment: Ok I will do that. Sorry I didn't know

Comment: I edited my question @AlexS1. Please tell me if this is good enough
Thank you

Comment: can you clean it up so that the variables are consistent? you say you want to graph x and c while varying x. Where is x called? and again your function inputs/outputs don't match; when you call the function, you need the same number of outputs. you should  clean up your code, run it in matlab, re-write your full question, post the clean code, and post the error message. If you are able to do that, you'll be more likely to get an answer from the community.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you call the answer by a different name in the command window. What is important is just the function name "func"